# Hide Visibility with FlatButton Flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

How do you change the visibility attribute in Flutter? I've tried some things myself, but nothing worked. The State Widget has been set into a StateFullWidget. Can someone help me?

```
class _StartGameState extends State<StartGame> {

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    bool _visibleStartGame = true;
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Visibility(
            visible: _visibleStartGame,//This has to been set to false.
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _visibleStartGame = false;
                  print(_visibleStartGame);
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, .5),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Touch to start',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Text('Hello, World!'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Make `bool _visibleStartGame = true;` a global variable because when `setState` is called, it will call `Widget build(...) {}` again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create your variable outside build function. Because build function will calling every time setState called and then your variable will set to true again.
This code will work

```
class _StartGameState extends State<StartGame> {
bool _visibleStartGame = true;
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Visibility(
            visible: _visibleStartGame,//This has to been set to false.
            child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  _visibleStartGame = false;
                  print(_visibleStartGame);
                });
              },
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, .5),
                child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                    'Touch to start',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Text('Hello, World!'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```